# How do I set up RESTFul URLs using ASP.NET MVC routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this URL:

`/controller/action/value`

and this action:

```
public ActionResult Get(string configName,string addParams)
{
}
```

How do I set up my routing table to get the routing engine bind the value to the `configName` parameter for any action in the `Config` controller?

Comment: With regards to the optional parameters, which version of MVC are you using to do this?

Comment: FYI, there is nothing RESTFUL about pretty URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "ValueMapping",                                            
      "config/{action}/{configName}/{addParams}",          
      new { controller = "Config", action = "Index", configName= UrlParameter.Optional, addParams = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults);
```

Setting default Controller to Home, with a Default Action of Index

So the Url:
`/config/get/configNameValue/AddParamValue`

would match this Method:

```
public ActionResult Get(string configName,string addParams)
{
//Do Stuff 
}
```

Comment: I guess this works for the whole application, but I need it only for the Config controller.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first off, that is incomplete. You don't have a method name.

Secondly, this will already work with URLs of the format:

/controller/action?configName=foo&addparams=bar

Here's how to do it with pretty routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "YourMapping",                                            
      "{controller}/{action}/{configName}/{addParams}");
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "YourMapping",                                            
      "{controller}/{configName}/{addParams}",     
      new {
          controller = "YourController",
          action = "YourAction"
      },
      new {
          controller = "YourController"  // Constraint
      });
```

if you want to exclude the action from the URL.

Comment: Ups, I added the action name. Yes I know but I'd like to have the url like /config/get/value. The second parameter is optional.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a new route above the default

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Config", 
  "config/{action}/{configName}/{addParams}",
  new { controller = "Config", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Which will allow you to use the route `/config/actionName/configName/addParamsValue`.  Your other routes should be unaffected by this.